# Corrupted React component name?

Tags: reactjs, git

This is an unusual one.

I commited a git branch, merged it, then hit undo on the merge. If I roll back to the commit (that had just been working) I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
    at UniqueComponentName (UniqueComponentName.js:13:1)
```

Line 13 is the opening declaration of the functional component:

```
export const UniqueComponentName = ({ side, mode, menuJSON, pcbData, ...props }) => {
```

I thought, initially, it was a problem with an 'includes' in the component but trial and error led me to discover the following:

1. A brand new component named UniqueComponentName, made with a
   template that works under any other name, still throws this error.
2. If I don't include the UniqueComponentName component in any other
   component, the app performs fine.
3. As soon as I include it, the error above is thrown. Again, the
   contents of UniqueComponentName are irrelevant as I can literally
   copy and paste another working component and the error comes up.

I'm wondering if it's possible that the merge and undo merge corrupted some reference to UniqueComponentName? It's a long shot, I'm aware, but I'm there has been a lot of work since the last commit.

---

#### Further info:

If of relevance:

- Reactjs is running off the standard create-react-app server locally.
- I have been staging commits locally, and using a 3rd party build
  pipeline to run builds on anything I push to github. The builds are hosted an a remote server that isn't involved here. As far as I
  know, there's no production builds locally : I just hit save on any
  file as I'm working on it and see webpack compiles, browser updates,
  etc.
- I'm considering starting up a fresh create-react-app project and bringing in all the /src files from the current project, to see if mt theory holds up.

Comment: Are you testing this on an old build? One that failed?

Comment: I would've asked the same as @0stone0.  Even re-clone and rebuild for good measure.

Comment: @0stone0 This is just a dev compile running on the standard server from create-react-app. I didn't get any more fancy than that so, to the best of my knowlege - no. But please correct if I'm naive about my understanding of what constitutes an old build. I've added further info into the original question.

Comment: Please delete the following folder, restart the dev-server, and try again: `node_modules/.cache`

Comment: The key is to pinpoint where your code reads `sth.includes`. This info is not revealed in your question.

Comment: Regarding line:13, don’t trust it. It could be corrupted sourcemap giving wrong info. You need to look at real compiled code run in browser.

Comment: @0stone0 You're a life-saver! delete that specific cache folder fixed the issue. I had no idea where to begin to look, or what was cached there, so this was really useful. If you want to suggest this as an actual answer I can accept it.

Comment: @hackape Many thanks for the tips. I hadn't revealed this in my question as I'd no idea that was pertinent (I'd never even heard of it before) but this would have been my next step in deducting the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by create-react-app serving **old bundle files**.

Those files are located in the `node_modules/.cache/` folder.

---

Solution;

1. Delete the `node_modules/.cache/` folder
2. Restart your dev-server

React should now re-create all the bundle files, sourcemaps, etc..

---

<sub>- [*Old* git issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10301) with some in-depth details</sub>